# How to return name of table of grade when save like json?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have two tables, users and grades.

**users table**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('grade_id')->nullable();
    }
}
```

**grades table**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('grades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I save id of grade with `json_encode`,

[image: json]

I save in field like this

```php
$user->grade_id = json_encode($request->input('grade_id'));
```

I want to return the `grade name` but I did not solve my problem

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $grades = Grade::all();
    return view('index', compact('grades');
}
```

**User.php**

```php
public function grade()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@if(isset(auth()->user()->grade_id)  && !empty(auth()->user()->grade_id))
<?php
    $grade = json_decode(auth()->user()->grade->name, true);
    @foreach($grade as $key=>$item)
        <li>
            <div class="grade">{{ $grade[$key] }}</div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
?>
@endif
```

I get this errpr

> Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Bad answer

You save an array of ids in the users table. Then when you do `$grade = json_decode(auth()->user()->grade->name)` you get something you don't want to have. Indeed, the value of `auth()->user()->grade` is `["8", "8"]`, this is not a grade model. Now you should understand why this `$grade = json_decode(auth()->user()->grade->name)` fail: you're trying to get `name` property of a non object (as `user()->grade` is just an array).

To solve it badly (read the next part of my answer) you can just do this in your controller (you shouldn't do any `<?php ?>` in your view files):

```php
public function index()
{
    $grades_ids = json_decode(auth()->user()->grade); // ["8", "8"]
    $grades = Grade::whereIn('id', $grades_ids)->get(); // Eloquent collection
    return view('index', compact('grades');
}
```

And use it in your view:

```
@if($grades->count())
    <ul>
    @foreach($grades as $grade)
        <li>
            <div class="grade">{{ $grade->id }}</div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

## Good answer

Here you have a typical many to many relationships. A grade can have multiple users, and a user can have multiple grades. Then you should think of [using a pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) rather than a encoding several `grade_id` in json.

Create a `users` table:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
    }
 }
```

Then you create your grades table:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('grades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then you create the new `user_grade_table`:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_grade', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'grade_id']);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('grade_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('grade_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('user_grade', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropPrimary('user_grade_user_id_grade_id_primary');
        $table->dropForeign('user_grade_user_id_foreign');
        $table->dropForeign('user_grade_grade_id_foreign');
    });
    Schema::dropIfExists('user_grade');
}
```

Don't forget to run the migrations. When this is done, you have to update your models, adding the belongs to many on both models.

**User model**

```php
public function grades()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Grade::class, 'user_grade', 'user_id', 'grade_id');
}
```

Same for **grade model**:

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_grade', 'grade_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Finally you can use it in your blade file:

```php
@if($grades = auth()->user()->grades)
    <ul>
    @foreach($grades as $grade)
        <li>
            <div class="grade">{{ $grade->name }}</div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```